# How to find out the availability status of a Web API from a Windows Store application

Tags: windows-store-apps, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Line-of-Business (LoB) Windows 8.1 Store application I developed for a client. The client side-loads it on several Windows 10 tablets. They use it in an environment where WiFi is spotty at best and they would like to get some sort of notification inside the app, regardless of what page they are on, notification that will let them know that they've lost connectivity to the network. I have created a method on my Web API that is not hitting the repository (database). Instead, it quickly returns some static information regarding my Web API, such as version, date and time of the invocation and some trademark stuff that I'm required to return. I thought of calling this method at precise intervals of time and when there's no response, assume that the Web API connectivity is lost. In my main page, the first one displayed when the application is started, I have the following stuff in the constructor of my view model:

```
_webApiStatusTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
_webApiStatusTimer.Tick += OnCheckWebApiStatusEvent;
_webApiStatusTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);

_webApiStatusTimer.Start();
```

Then, the event handler is implemented like this:

```
private async void OnCheckWebApiStatusEvent(object sender, object e)
{
   // stop the timer
   _webApiStatusTimer.Stop();

   // refresh the search
   var webApiInfo = await _webApiClient.GetWebApiInfo();

   // add all returned records in the list
   if (webApiInfo == null)
   {
      var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(@"The application has lost connection with the back-end Web API!");
      await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

      // restart the timer
      _webApiStatusTimer.Start();
   }
}
```

When the Web API connection is lost, I get a nice popup message that informs me that the Web API is no longer available. The problem I have is that after a while, especially if I navigate away from the first page but not necessary, I get an UnauthorizedAccessException in my application.

I use the DispatcherTimer since my understanding is that this is compatible with 
UI threads, but obviously, I still do something wrong. Anyone cares to set me on the right path?

Also, if you did something similar and found a much better approach, I'd love to hear about your solution.

Thanks in advance,
Eddie

Answer (score 0):

First, If you are using Windows Store Apps, then you could possibly use a Background task to check poll for the status of the web api instead of putting this responsibility on your view model, its not the viewmodels concern

Second, if you are connecting from your Windows store app to your API then one successful authentication/ authorization for the first time, how and where do you store the token (assuming you are using token authentication). If you are (and ideally you should), is there a timer that you start which is set to the token expiration time? Is your local storage getting flushed somehow and loosing the aurthorization data?

Need more information.